# Redirection to error page in Amazon S3 static website

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-headers

i have a bucket and enabled static web site hosting in it.

Say i have only two files in the bucket (index.html) and (error.html)

If a request is hit with test.html, either access denied or no such key error is thrown.

How to redirect to error.html in case of such errors ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the S3 Management Console, open the properties of your bucket and enable the "Static Website Hosting". It will ask you for an index page and an error page and provide you an endpoint for your static website.

See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

Comment: I have followed it, but still redirection to error page is not happening.

Comment: Check that you are using the correct endpoint URL (*s3-website-*)