# How to solve "x-cache: Error from cloudfront" on SPA

Tags: amazon-s3, react-router, amazon-cloudfront, static-site

We are having issues trying to make working a SPA with a client router (react router). We are using the concept of have a `DOMAIN -> CDN (CloudFront) -> S3` for serving our static files.

We have configured the S3 for serving static files. The CDN are configured to have the origin from the S3 and we have configured custom error pages to catch errors:

[image]

with this configuration we can catch errors like this:

```
https://www.example.com/custom-url
```

The CDN will redirect all the 404/403 errors to the main `index.html` and `react router` will get the correct routing.

We have working our site, and the client router is working fine, but we have a problem with the response of our CDN with `x-cache: Error from cloudfront`:

[image]

If we access to the main url `https://www.example.com` without any query param (not query string) all works fine.

How can I solved this problem and make that all my dynamic URLs work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When you visit `http://mywebsite.com` the request will hit the `index.html` file in S3. Then you might click a button and go to `http://mywebsite.com/stats` which is an internal route of your SPA app. Thus, it will not trigger any backend request.

But if you reload the page, `http://mywebsite.com/stats` will be sent to S3 as your browser does not know that you are running an SPA frontend.

S3 will return 403 error with index.html and Cloudfront will send you the error.

Solution is using an edge lambda function in Cloudfront. Here an example:

```
const path = require('path')

exports.handler = (evt, ctx, cb) => {
    const {request} = evt.Records[0].cf

    if (!path.extname(request.uri)) {
        request.uri = '/index.html'
    }

    cb(null, request)
}
```

Source: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-host-a-single-page-application-with-aws-cloudfront-and-lambda-edge-39ce7b036da2

Comment: Correct. So, basically, you can also ignore it.

Comment: You don't need a lambda. You can configure Error Responses in CloudFront. So for a 403 you can configure cloudfront to return 200 and return your index.html.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/GeneratingCustomErrorResponses.html

Comment: @brendonparker This doesn't fix the issue with `x-cache: Error from cloudfront` header.  In this situation, I think it also prevents CloudFront Functions from running.

Answer (score 4):

Amazon CloudFront can get tricky with its configuration and debugging an error code - to trace it back to its root cause can take several hours. However, you might want to make the following checks before you get into the logs.

---

## Bucket Name!

The bucket names should match the names of the website that you are hosting.

> For instance, to host **your-domain.com** website on Amazon S3, you would create a bucket named **your-domain.com**.
>
> To host a website under **www.your-domain.com**, you would name the bucket **www.your-domain.com**.

Its a best practice, to create buckets for both your-domain.com and www.your-domain.com.

Use the existing logic in your settings/configuration for any one of these buckets and use it to serve the static website. Use the other bucket to redirect the request to the original bucket.

[image: Bucket Redirection Settings]

Honestly, this wouldn't be causing you the trouble since you've integrated your system with Amazon CloudFront, which can be configured to use an Amazon S3 bucket of any name.

With Amazon CloudFront, users that visit your domain will directly fetch data from the CloudFront distribution which in turn caches contents from our S3 bucket.

---

## Configuring the distribution's Origin Settings.

While creating a distribution with Amazon CloudFront make note of the associated Amazon S3 endpoint with the Origin Domain Name. Make sure to use the web site endpoint and **NOT** the REST endpoint. Don't use the endpoint auto-suggested by CloudFront.

There is a difference in the behavior as explained in the Amazon Web Services [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html#WebsiteRestEndpointDiff)

---

## **4XX** Error Code!

From your console logs, it suggests distribution instance is trying to access a forbidden element, page or resource and hence the 403 status code.

While the 404 is merely a result of page not found. However, after the error redirection - as handled in your configuration, the user is redirected back to `index.html` where it encounters the 403.

More information on - [How CloudFront Processes and Caches HTTP 4xx and 5xx Status Codes from Your Origin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/HTTPStatusCodes.html)

---

#### Other usual suspects include Caching Configurations for Amazon CloudFront distribution, AWS Route53 settings, and Amazon Certificate Manager.

As mentioned in the beginning it can get quite perplexing while tracking such errors. Let us know if the above helps. Also, I would really appreciate it if you could post updates on your investigations and findings.

Thanks for the read.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same solution as @jackops above, but I solved it with a different lambda function.

```
function handler(event){
// Check if the request is for an internal route (doesn't have a file extension)
if (!event.request.uri.includes('.')) {
    event.request.uri = '/index.html'; 
   }

return event.request;
}
```

Another possible solution.

Ensure that your server (in this case, AWS S3 and CloudFront) is configured to handle all requests, including those for routes within your SPA, by redirecting them to the `index.html` file. This ensures that the server returns the SPA's main page for any route requested.

In CloudFront, you can configure a custom error response to redirect all `403 / 404` errors to the `index.html` file. Here's how:

- Go to your CloudFront distribution settings.
- Under the "Error Pages" section, add a custom error response.
- Set the HTTP error code to `"403: Forbidden"` / `"404: Not Found"` and set the "Response Page Path" to `/index.html`.
- Save the configuration.

This configuration tells CloudFront to serve the `index.html` page for any 404 error, effectively redirecting all route requests to the main page.