# SOLVED___Using AWS S3 to Webhost is giving no key error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-hosting

I am trying to host a site with muliple paths on a S3 Bucket. Is this an available option ?

## These two work on my local machine.

localhost:3000

localhost:3000/policy

## Trying to host this on S3 is giving me no key error

example.com <-- Works

example.com/policy  <-- does not work with no key error

## Exact Error

404 Not Found
Code: NoSuchKey

Message: The specified key does not exist.

Key: policy

## I should mention

I am using React-Router-Dom switch on the App that is working on localhost

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/policy"><PolicyComponent><Route>
    <Route path="/"><HomePageComponent><Route>
<Switch>
```

Comment: By "no key error", can you be more specific? Is it an HTTP 404 response with NoSuchKey?

Comment: @jarmod edit done

Comment: Is this a completely static website? Is there a document named `policy` in the root of the S3 bucket? Also, see https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/404-error-nosuchkey-s3/

Comment: it's not a static website, but it is a complete client side only website

Answer (score 6):

[react router doesn't work in aws s3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218979/react-router-doesnt-work-in-aws-s3-bucket)

Very Simple Fix,

All I needed to do was indicate any errors to index.html

I did not provide index.html on the set up.

Answer (score 0):

If the html file name is 'policy.html', they you need to reference it as such, if you want the url to just be example.com/policy, you would create a folder called 'policy' under the root and put the contents in a file called index.html in that bucket.

Comment: Can S3 handle the incoming of random paths. Because I have localhost:3000/randomString working.....wondering if I need to switch to dynamic hosting, even though my app is technically server-less