# React app SPA on S3 AWS while refreshing the page shows 404 page

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, deployment, single-page-application, amazon-cloudfront

I have a **SPA** made with **React JS** on a **S3 Bucket** and I’m using **Cloud Front to work through HTTPS and with a custom domain**. When I refresh the page - if I have another Route that is not the BASE_URL **(for example domain.com/something)**, S3 sends me a 404 error.

I also tried redirecting the error page to BASE_URL but it doesn’t work, it redirects me to the Http default domain that S3 provides me and again, it gives me an 404 error page.

**I don’t know if there exists an alternative way to keep the URL without any change (domain.com/page) and avoid the 404 error the way a web server (apache) handles.**

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218979/react-router-doesnt-work-in-aws-s3-bucket) solve your issue?

Answer (score 10):

If you are using CloudFront to host s3 website, the effective way to get rid of `404` on reload of non-index route like `www.google.com/about` or similar non `/` is by the following steps:

1. Go to your CloudFront distribution
2. Go to Error Pages
3. Create a new error page with the following params:

```
    HTTP Error Code: 404
    TTL: 0
    Custom Error Response: Yes
    Response Page Path: /index.html
    HTTP Response Code: 200
```

enjoy

credits going to this article https://gist.github.com/bradwestfall/b5b0e450015dbc9b4e56e5f398df48ff

Comment: tks for that, Artem. It saved my day

Comment: Important note: using error pages to solve a routing problem, you set CSP and other security headers!

Answer (score 2):

You have two options. Either use CloudFront error page as a catch-all that redirects to / (you mentioned you tried setting an error page but did not detail what you did. This should work). The downside is that it will respond with the HTML page for *all* not found paths, even for mistyped CSS paths, for example.

The other solution is to use Lambda@Edge to rewrite the origin request path. This is a more customizable solution and you can define which paths you want to redirect to the root.

Comment: Do you happen to have an example of such a Lambda@Edge?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Though AWS released CloudFront functions that provide an easier alternative to this than Lambda@Edge: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-cloudfront-functions-run-your-code-at-the-edge-with-low-latency-at-any-scale/