# How to setup Cloudfront & S3 to point to index.html for every route?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js

I have a NextJS application hosted on AWS. My folder structure is like this:

```
- index.html

- /articles
-- index.html

-- /article1
---- /index.html

-- /article2
---- /index.html
.
.
.
```

How do I set the routing to that /articles points to /articles/index.html, /article1 points to /article1/index.html and so on. Every folder in my app has a corresponding /index.html. I have hosted my side on S3 and I am using cloudfront. I have already tried setting the default root object to /index.html but it looks like it only sets it for the root/domain, not the subfolders.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not neeed Cloudfront functions. Following S3 settings set index.html as default for all folders, not only the root.

[image]

Comment: So I did this. It works if I use the S3 origin URL to browse my site. However, if I use my domain name (mapped to cloudfront), then it works as long as I don't refresh the page. If I refresh the page, I get S3 bucket's access denied message. I don't get the same problem though when I refresh the page while using the S3 origin URL. Any idea what's wrong? I was looking and I found the suggestion to add 403 and 400 page for cloudfront but that takes the user back to homepage on refresh.

Comment: 400 or 403 pages are only needed for SPAs where all the routing happens on client side. For real website with folders it's not relevant.
The reason it doesn't work for you is probably because you are trying to use REST endpoint of the S3 bucket and not Website endpoint. Read more here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/

Comment: This saved me. I wasn't intentionally using the REST endpoint of S3. I just picked form the dropdown list in the CF origin. But, the MOST important piece of information in the doc was "Don't select the bucket from the dropdown list. The dropdown list includes only the S3 Bucket REST API endpoints that aren't used in this configuration." I did this and it fixed the problem. Thanks so much. I have been banging my head on this for 3 weeks now.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need a [Cloud Function](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-cloudfront-functions-run-your-code-at-the-edge-with-low-latency-at-any-scale/). Start from the basic sample [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-functions/tree/main/url-rewrite-single-page-apps) that appends index.html to the URI and modify it for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Use a cloudfront function, ie:

```
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;
    var uri = request.uri;
    
    if (uri !== '' && uri !== '/' && uri.indexOf('.') === -1) {
        request.uri = uri + '.html';
    }
    return request;
}
```