# static website api request rewritten domain

Tags: github-pages, npm-build

I apologize if similar question already put, I am a beginner in this area and I was only able to find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67430852/static-react-website-on-s3-request-url-to-api-rewritten-to-own-url), which refers to S3 I am not using. Searching wild web brings me in all cases to a [custom domain solution](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site) which I believe is either not relevant for this issue.

1. I have a node.js React app, which is created from [this repository](https://github.com/gooddata/gooddata-create-gooddata-react-app) , and makes a request to `https://domain/api/v1/profile`.
2. As I am satisfied what it does in localhost development, I am building it (with `react-scripts build` if relevant) and deploying to a separate github repository (that basically holds all the build files in main branch).
3. Further [set up of github-pages](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site) in this repository brings up a web page in format `https://username.github.io`
4. When I open up Console (right click - Inspect - console tab) I can see that the app gets a 404 from requesting `https://username.github.io/api/v1/profile` - basically my domain from point 1 is nulled or replaced with github homepage.

Can someone please explain to me how can I make a request from point 1 in a deployed github page? I am not sure if I submitted all necessary info for a response, please fell free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the initial logic inherited from the repository (in point 1)
is prepared but not used by default and environment variable `REACT_APP_SET_HOSTNAME` needs to be added there prior building the project (point 2).

The process is described in the original repository [here](https://github.com/gooddata/gooddata-create-gooddata-react-app/blob/master/bootstrap/README--tiger.md) but googling around (and searching github) shows me it is not a common pattern. I would be grateful if someone can link here more general approach as other users can also benefit, otherwise I may accept this one as working solution.