# Access from amplify front to elastic beanstalk back

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a next application deployed on aws amplify and a node.js application deployed on elastic beanstalk. Both are deployed fine.

I try to access from the front by calling the back directly from the code with axios like so axios.post(url, object).

On my machine the calls work ok, in aws I don't see the call in the network part of the browser and no console.log get displayed.

As the deployed back seems to work fine I guess the error is in the deployed next front but as I deployed with amplify I don't know where to start searching for the issue.

Any guess?

Thanks

Comment: If anyone comes across this, I solved it coming by this thread  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218979/react-router-doesnt-work-in-aws-s3-bucket and fixed the issue by using HashRouter instead of Router