# Why does React app served by cloudfront doesn't render component

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, react-router-dom, auth0

I am pretty new to React and front end world.So ignore mistakes.

So i am using auth0 for authentication in my react app. Login button is a component which redirecta to auth0 authentication button and upon login user can go to /profile component. Using react router for going to profile component.

All this works perfectly in localhost.
But the moment i deployed on s3 and cloudfront. it shows profile key not found so based on various solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58978355/13126651)on stack now add i can see my go to profile component however the page is entirely blank nothing is being render on profile component.

**UPDATE :- the error is definitely related to cloudfront, because if i directly access my s3 bucket website endpoint,it renders everything works.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by add error response 403 404 for cloud front.

Comment: Worked. But I could not find the reason why 403 is necessary, while iundex.html was able to get all the static files without 403 error. Just page was blank.