# Adding HTTP Security Headers Using Lambda@Edge and Amazon CloudFront for All routes (error routes)

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I am using this doc https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/adding-http-security-headers-using-lambdaedge-and-amazon-cloudfront/

I am using a react app in S3 bucket, with a cloudfront CDN. I have added a lambdaedge to add a security header

```
 headers['x-frame-options'] = [{key: 'X-Frame-Options', value: 'DENY'}]; 
 headers['x-xss-protection'] = [{key: 'X-XSS-Protection', value: '1; mode=block'}];
```

It is working fine for the homepage (mySite.com):
[image]

But it doesn't work for a different route, example mySite.com/login
[image]

When I check the error behavior in cloudFront, there are no options to add a header

[image]

Why this page `/login` is in error? Because of [react router doesn't work in aws s3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218979/react-router-doesnt-work-in-aws-s3-bucket)

Answer (score 1):

The way that I solved this was to implement an origin request Lambda@Edge function that validates the `event.Records[0].cf.request.uri` value against a whitelist of known files and paths in the S3 origin. If the path doesn't match the whitelist, it updates the uri value to `/index.html` which allows the React app handle the request.

With this change, there will no longer be any 404 requests, which means the response will successfully pass through the origin response Lambda@Edge function which adds the response headers.

Answer (score 1):

We solve this by using this feature called policy response headers in cloudfront. It add headers in all cases even in error response.

Doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-managed-response-headers-policies.html

We implemented it with terraform

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_response_headers_policy" "my_name" {
  name    = "policy-response-headers-my-name"
  comment = "Add security headers to responses"

  security_headers_config {

    xss_protection {
      mode_block = true
      override   = true
      protection = true
    }
    frame_options {
      frame_option = "DENY"
      override     = true
    }
    content_type_options {
      override = true
    }
    content_security_policy {
      content_security_policy = "frame-ancestors 'none'"
      override                = true
    }
    referrer_policy {
      referrer_policy = "same-origin"
      override        = true
    }
    strict_transport_security {
      access_control_max_age_sec = 63072000
      override                   = true
    }
    origin_override = true
  }
}
```