# How do I prevent VueRouter from treating links to static files as routes?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, vite, aws-amplify

I'm using Vue3/VueRouter/Vite to render a static site hosted on AWS Amplify. Routing is working well, however it's a bit over eager and treats links to static files (in my case, .zip) hosted in `public` as routes, which then jump to the 404 catch-all route.

My understanding from previous versions of Vue/VueRouter was that you could use `<a>` tags instead of `<router-link>` components to perform GETs instead of router links, but this is what I'm trying with no luck.

I only experience this behaviour when using the application on the remote hosted server (production). Testing the site via localhost/dev behaves as expected.

How can I instruct VueRouter to fetch these static files instead of attempting/failing to route to them?

**Repro:** Add the following line to the component:

`<a target="_blank" href="https://example.com/file.zip">File Download</a>`

**Expected:** Clicking the link takes you to a download of the file on the server.

**Result:** Clicking the link takes you to `https://example.com/file.zip` as a route, where `file.zip` is the route path. This results in the display of the 404 page.

Comment: sounds like issue with the web server.  if the physical file is on the hosting server it may need to be configured to serve static files and to **not** redirect file-based URLs back to your SPA

Comment: In your case, since you don't want to use `router-link` and want to use a direct link, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70059194/4800344) should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I was able to find the solution for AWS Amplify.

I had to modify the default rewrite/redirect rule to include .zip files:

`</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>`

Became:

`</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(zip|css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>`

With a target address of `index.html` and code of `200` (rewrite)