# React - access child paths directly using BrowserRouter?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, browser-history

I use `BrowserRouter` as React Router Dom, and while I try to access a specific path say `http://localhost:3000/recoverPassword`, the URL can't be resolved. I can't go for `HashRouter` as the client is not that impressed to see the `#` in the URL. I came across the reason and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40338808/4694013) is how we able to rectify it using web-pack. But I don't use web-pack in my project. So I wanted to know whether is there any alternative approach without using any module bundlers?

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={SignIn} />
          <Route exact path="/recoverPassword" component={RecoverPassword} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

**Note:**

Locally it works with no additional config, but when I deploy to Amazon AWS it couldn't resolve the path.

**Update #1**

We can configure s3 bucket to resolve the error by pointing the error document also to `index.html` like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543983/redirection-to-error-page-in-amazon-s3-static-website/23544903#23544903) explains. The `create-react-app` hash trick shall do the remaining with `BrowserRouter`.

[image]

> But my team had hosted the build to production in EC2, I don't have
> the access to it currently, need to have a look at how the same can be
> configured out there. Meantime it would be great if someone can share
> any info as an answer regarding how to deal this in EC2.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to serve the files?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings I don't use any module bundlers. I just create the build using `npm run build` then deploy.

Comment: That seems odd. Then what are you using `build` for? Are you using `create-react-app`?

Comment: Yeah, I created the skeleton using [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html)

Comment: Well, then you are using `webpack` underneath. `create-react-app` has it's own deployment instructions [page](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing)

Comment: You just have to make sure that you send index.html link with AWS no matter what Route you are on

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Being a newbie in the web dev, I couldn't quit follow what u meant, could you pl. more elaborate?

Comment: Say your server name is `ReactApp.com` then for paths `ReactApp.com/recoverPassword` or `ReactApp.com` , AWS should just return index.html file from your build.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri So do I need to have any configuration for that, in project or in aws server?

Comment: You need to have that config in AWS server

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Okay, let me check. Meantime if you can explain how to achieve it as an answer it would be great for newbies like me. Thanks.

Comment: @Stella Your issue seems to have been resolved, but I would recommend going through [this blog](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh/)...it will help you understand what is going on and how to deal with it.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I host the build to aws s3 bucket for testing purpose, so I resolved the *404* error by pointing the error document also to `index.html` like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23544903/4817630) explains. The `create-react-app` hash trick shall do the remaining with `BrowserRouter`. But my team had hosted the build to production in EC2, I don't have the access to it currently, need to have a look at how the same can be configured out there.